# rpm: what does the release number in `gpg-pubkey-<verstion>-<release>` stands for?

Tags: linux, gnupg, rpm

GnuPG public keys that are imported into the RPM keyring with:

```
rpm --import PUBKEY_FILE
```

can be queried with

```
rpm -q gpg-pubkey-<key-id>
```

For example the CentOS4 key:

```
pub  1024D/443E1821 2005-02-25 CentOS-4 key <centos-4key@centos.org>
     Key fingerprint = 31EA 27E5 6F79 0C18 AD79  18DF A53D 0BAB 443E 1821
sub  2048g/06870DBC 2005-02-25 [expires: 2015-02-23]
```

can be queried with

```
rpm -q gpg-pubkey-443e1821
```

and the result is:

```
 gpg-pubkey-443e1821-421f218f
```

The RPM's version number `443e1821` corresponds to the key id `0x443e1821` but **what the release number `421f218f` stands for?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cross posted [this question on LinuxExchange](http://linuxexchange.org/questions/1197/rpm-what-does-the-release-number-in-gpg-pubkey-verstion-release-stands-for), and [got the answer there](http://linuxexchange.org/questions/1197/rpm-what-does-the-release-number-in-gpg-pubkey-verstion-release-stands-for/1198#1198).

In short the release number: 421f218f, is the Unix time of the key creation:

```
$ date -d "1970-1-1 + $((0x421f218f)) sec"
Fri Feb 25 13:01:03 IST 2005
```